# No value can be display in alert prompt while selecting Physical Radio button

Tags: javascript, html, nan

I think there is a problem in the else if loop. If I convert else if to if it prints the last value of exp.
I also try many different ways such as make different functions for a particular radio button. But it may not work.
Code:

```
    '''<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Welcome TO CVSS Cal</title>
        <style>
            input:checked+label{background: green; border: 1px solid green; color: #FFF}
            input { display: none; width:auto; }
            label:hover { background: #666666; color: #ffffff; border: 1px solid #666666 }
            label {
        background: #cccccc; display: inline-block; margin: 3px; padding: 2px 5px; border: 0; cursor: pointer; font-size: 90%;
        border-radius: 5px; color: #666666; border: 1px solid #999999;
        user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: -moz-none; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none;
      }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var av;
            function handleClick(avn){
                if (document.getElementsByName("AVN")) {
                    avn = 0.85;
                    av = avn;
                }
                else if (document.getElementsById("AVA")){
                    avn = 0.77;
                    av = avn;
                }
            }
            function handleExploit(exp){
                exp=8.22*av;
                alert(exp);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form  method="post">
    <fieldset style="border-radius: 10px;">
        <h3>Attack Vector</h3>
    <input name="AVN" value="N" id="AV_N" type="radio" onclick="handleClick(this)"><label for="AV_N" id="AV_N_label">Network</label>
        <input name="AVA" value="A" id="AV_A" type="radio" onclick="handleClick(this)"><label for="AV_A" id="AV_A_label">Adjacent</label>
        <input name="AVP" value="P" id="AV_P" type="radio"><label for="AV_P" id="AV_P_label">Physical</label>
    <input name="AVL" value="L" id="AV_L" type="radio"><label for="AV_L" id="AV_L_label">Local</label><br><br>
        
        <button value="cvss" id="cvss" name="cvss_button" onclick="handleExploit(this)">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>



    <script type="text/javascript">
            var av;
            function handleClick(avn){
                if (document.getElementsByName("AVN")) {
                    avn = 0.85;
                    av = avn;
                }
                else if (document.getElementsById("AVA")){
                    avn = 0.77;
                    av = avn;
                }
            }
            function handleExploit(exp){
                exp=8.22*av;
                alert(exp);
            }
        </script>
    <style>
            input:checked+label{background: green; border: 1px solid green; color: #FFF}
            input { display: none; width:auto; }
            label:hover { background: #666666; color: #ffffff; border: 1px solid #666666 }
            label {
        background: #cccccc; display: inline-block; margin: 3px; padding: 2px 5px; border: 0; cursor: pointer; font-size: 90%;
        border-radius: 5px; color: #666666; border: 1px solid #999999;
        user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: -moz-none; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none;
      }
        </style>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Welcome TO CVSS Cal</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form  method="post">
    <fieldset style="border-radius: 10px;">
        <h3>Attack Vector</h3>
    <input name="AVN" value="N" id="AV_N" type="radio" onclick="handleClick(this)"><label for="AV_N" id="AV_N_label">Network</label>
        <input name="AVA" value="A" id="AV_A" type="radio" onclick="handleClick(this)"><label for="AV_A" id="AV_A_label">Adjacent</label>
        <input name="AVP" value="P" id="AV_P" type="radio"><label for="AV_P" id="AV_P_label">Physical</label>
    <input name="AVL" value="L" id="AV_L" type="radio"><label for="AV_L" id="AV_L_label">Local</label><br><br>
        
        <button value="cvss" id="cvss" name="cvss_button" onclick="handleExploit(this)">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>




        </form>
    </body>
    </html>'''
```

Here I select the Physical Radio button and click on Submit button no value can be print on the alert prompt.

Comment: Making the naming clear can make it easier to find the error.

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for submitting your question.
Please provide users with more details about your code so they can help you, maybe a clear general context.
Also please bear in mind that a snippet with confusing naming and too much superfluous code might be more difficult to read and reason about. Maybe remove the css ? And maybe -as Kayra suggested before- provide better names for HTML elements, variables and functions.